# If Which Piecewise-defined function

Tags: plotting, piecewise, conditional

How would I write a function using If and/or Which command for following Piecewise-defined function then plot the function

```
f(x)=1, if x<=1
f(x)=x^3, if -1<x<=1
f(x)=-1, if x>1
```

This what I have so far

```
f[x_] := If[(x <= -1) && (x < 1 || x <= 1), x^3, 
  Which[x <= -1, -1, x > 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Your function is confusing. You want $f(x) =1$ if $x\leq1$ and $f(x) = x^3$ if $x >1$? If so: `f[x_ /; x <= 1] := 1; f[x_ /; x > 1] := x^3;` of `f[x_] := If[x <= 1, 1, x^3];`.

Comment: For mathematical functions, you should try `Piecewise`: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html.

Answer (score 1):

Your function definition is inconsistent. Perhaps you meant,

```
f1[x_] = Piecewise[{{Sign[x], Abs[x] > 1}}, x^3];

f2[x_] := Clip[x^3];

Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, -2, 2},
 PlotStyle -> {
   Directive[Red, AbsoluteDashing[{5, 5}]],
   Directive[Blue, AbsoluteDashing[{7, 7}]]},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]